# saving value of jquery countdown timer in php session

Tags: php, jquery

I am using the following [Jquery flip timer](http://flipclockjs.com/) . I am using it as the countdown verison . My code is

```
var clock;

$(document).ready(function() {
    var clock;

    clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(<?php echo $total_time;  ?>, {
        clockFace: 'MinuteCounter',
        countdown: true,
        callbacks: {
            stop: function() {
                $('.message').html('The clock has stopped!')
            }
        }
    });

});
```

I am getting the time dynamic here in minutes . The problem is whenever i refresh the page the counter resets . How to save the counter's value so that it can resume from where it was before the page refresh ?

Comment: Put it in a cookie or local storage. I don't see how PHP can help, it runs on the server, not the client. Unless you want to send the timer to the server with AJAX, and have it put it in a session variable.

Answer (score 2):

What Barmar said is correct, you should use the localStorage[] variable. However, if for whatever reason you need to save it to $_SESSION, you should use ajax. Like so:

```
$.get('savetimer.php?timer=' + timer);
```

Like all client code, this can be manipulated by the user.

Comment: But how to make it save the realtime time ? when user refresh the page   then how this will be called ?

Comment: You can save it using localStorage. i.e. localStorage['timerValue'] = timer; (do this every second, or whenever the time changes, I guess) or if you do it with Ajax, same thing really. Just run the ajax code every second (or few seconds) to keep saving it to server. However this makes may network calls which is why it's recommended you use localStorage[]

Comment: You mean i should use settimeout so that i can send this value every second to a session ?

Comment: Just to clarify, does it show the countdown on the page? If so, where that occurs you would want to send an ajax request telling the server what the time it just set is

Comment: yes it shows a countdown on page . The value that is coming from datebase is 60 minutes and suppose a user by mistake refresh page the countdown reset to 60 minutes again . I am making a online test application so the countdown should be accurate

Answer (score 0):

I made this code and it works exactly the way i wanted thank you @Ezekiel for your help.

```
        var clock;

        $(document).ready(function() {
            var clock;

            clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(<?php echo $final_time;  ?>, {
                clockFace: 'MinuteCounter',
                countdown: true,
                callbacks: {
                    start: function() {
                        setInterval(function(){
                        var time  = clock.getTime();
                        //alert(time);
                            imStillAlive(time);
                        }, 2000);
                    },              
                    stop: function() {
                        $('.message').html('The clock has stopped!')
                    }
                }
            });

        });


function imStillAlive(time) { 

     $.post('modules/view_test/ajax.php?timer='+time,
     function(data){
        //alert("updated");
     });//post
}
```